# 10.10 irritating updater message

Tags: 10.10, updates, update-manager

As you all know 10.10 support has ended. thus whenever i start the update manager i get a dialog box saying

> Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore
>   You will not get any further security fixes or critical updates.
>   Please upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu Linux.

any way to remove this? that is really bugging me.
ps. updating to a newer version is not an option now
the screenshot
[image: The message]

Comment: Just disable update manager, there are no updates available, no reason to run it.

Comment: But i do have updates from other ppas...

Comment: Everything gets updated from the same repositories.

Comment: @mikewhatever-i have some launchpad ppas enabled and even after the support for 10.10 was withdrawn i got a few updates from those ppas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it!!!! Just open software sources and set `Release Upgrade` to `Never` under the `Updates tab`.This stops the message from recurring. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling updates?

Click System->Administration->Software Sources, Updates tab, and uncheck the 'Check for updates' box.

Comment: Nope, i still get the error.

Comment: How do you trigger the error?

Comment: i get that as soon as i start update manager.

Comment: When you start the update manager, it does what it is supposed to do, in other words, check for updates. Edit your sources list and comment out the maverick repositories.

Answer (score -1):

Click System-> Administration-> Software Sources, Updates tab, and uncheck the `Check for updates` box.

Go to terminal -> type `sudo apt-get update`-> enter
               -> type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` -> enter

Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04